# Scanf statement being ignored

Tags: c

My program is ignoring my scanf statement before the if statement that would take user input to close the program or to continue by adding new information(at the end of the while (1) inside of main).

```
int main (void)
{
while (1)
    {
        float weight = 0;   
        char animal , b;

        printf("Zoo Food Calculator: \n\n");
        printf("What is the animal type? \n [M]Mammal or [A]Amphibian or [R]Reptile: \n");
        scanf("%c", &animal);

        printf("What is the weight of the animal in pounds?:\n");
        scanf("%f", &weight);

        weight = round(weight);

        printf("weight in pounds: %f\n", weight);

        if (animal == 'M')
        {
             Mammals (weight) ;
             printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", Mammals(weight));
        }
        else if (animal == 'A')
        {
        Amphibians (weight) ;
        printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", 
Amphibians(weight));
        }

    else 
        {
            Reptiles (weight) ;
            printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a 
week!\n", Reptiles(weight));
        }

        printf("Do you want to input new information? Y/N \n");
        scanf("%c", &b);

        if (b == 'N' || b == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }    
     }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You are calling them 2x  Once before the `printf` and once during. Store the returned value and use that in the `printf`.

Comment: Because you're calling each of them twice. Read your code. Remember a function call is `thefunction(theparam)`. Now read your code again. If that's not enough, use a debugger to step through it to see what's happening.

Comment: BTW, voting to close as a typographical error or unable to reproduce. *Why are my functions being called twice when I call them twice?* isn't really a question that's going to be of use to future readers.

Comment: Also [The program doesn't stop on scanf("%c", &ch) line, why?](//stackoverflow.com/q/20306659)

Comment: When `scanf()` processes the number, it leaves the newline in the input buffer, unread.  Your `"%c"` format happily reads the newline; the newline is neither `'N'` nor `'n'` so you are deemed to want to put in more information.  Use `" %c"` in both places where you use `"%c"`; that will skip optional white space and wait for new input that is not a white space character.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why my program is running the functions (Mammals, Amphibians, Reptiles) twice.

You are calling the functions twice:

```
Mammals (weight);  //<-- first time
printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", Mammals(weight));
//                                                             ^
//                                                         second time
```

> It is also ignoring my scanf statement before the if statement that would take user input to close

That's because the newline character is still in the input buffer after this
`scanf`:

```
scanf("%f", &weight);
```

`%f` converts the float but the newline (entered when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed) is not
part of the float, so it remains in the input buffer. The next `scanf`

```
scanf("%c", &b);
```

reads the newline that was in the input buffer, that's why it seems that "it has
been ignored". You have to "clear" the input buffer, you can use this
function:

```
void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

and call it after `scanf("%f", &weight);`, like this:

```
printf("What is the weight of the animal in pounds?:\n");
scanf("%f", &weight);
clear_stdin();
```

Another alternative if you don't want to use the `clear_stdin` function, would
be to add an empty space in the `scanf` format like this:

```
scanf(" %c", &b);
```

with the empty space `scanf` will ignore the empty spaces, newline and tabs in
the input buffer. For more information about the format string for `scanf`,
please take a look at the [documentation of `scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Comment: Thanks, a bunch. I thought that as long as i passed an initialized variable into the function's parameters the printf would recognize that all i am asking for is the return value.

Comment: @CuriousNemo the computer executes exactly that what you tell him to do, no function does look ahead and tries to guess what the programmer intentions might be. If you call a function twice, it gets executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected version:

```
void flush() //to clear the buffer to remove whitespaces after your input
{
    int n;
    while((n = getchar()) != 10 && n != -1);
}

int main ()
{
    for(;;) //this is a 'better' version of while(1), according to some
    {
        float weight = 0;
        char animal , b;

        printf("Zoo Food Calculator: \n\n");
        printf("What is the animal type? \n [M]Mammal or [A]Amphibian or [R]Reptile: \n");
        scanf("%c", &animal);

        flush();

        printf("What is the weight of the animal in pounds?:\n");
        scanf("%f", &weight);

        flush(); //to remove the Line Feed [Carriage Return]

        weight = (float) round((double) weight);

        printf("weight in pounds: %f\n", weight);

        float food; //we use this as variable for the result of your functions

        if (animal == 'M')
        {
            food = Mammals (weight); //you need to save the return value
            printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", food);
        }
        else if (animal == 'A')
        {
            food = Amphibians (weight);
            printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", food);
        }

        else
        {
            food = Reptiles (weight);
            printf("For this animal you'll need %f lbs of food a week!\n", food);
        }

        printf("Do you want to input new information? Y/N \n");
        scanf("%c", &b);

        flush();

        if (b == 'N' || b == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

instead of saving the return value under 'food' and afterwards using that in the printf, you could also use the printf u had but remove the first call.

Comment: Don't use "magic" number like 10 and -1, use `'\n'` and `EOF` instead.